# Java Get String Between Two Strings

Tags: java

want to ask how to get the "200" value with this type of pattern? I need the simplest and easiest way without adding extra dependency library. I don't want the substring(11, s.length() - 1) method.

```
~PHONE_IDX=200~PHONE_DD=100~PHONE_KK=50~
```

Comment: You can use regex with [Patter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Comment: Here is an regex which select value of `PHONE_IDX`: `(?<=~PHONE_IDX=)(\d+)(?=~)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex to accomplish this, by searching for the ~PHONE_characters=digits pattern, like so:

```
String str = "~PHONE_IDX=200~PHONE_DD=100~PHONE_KK=50~";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("~PHONE_(?<attribute>\\w+)=(?<value>\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);//matcher for string
while(m.find())
{
  System.out.println("Next group: "+m.group());
  System.out.println("Attribute: "+m.group("attribute"));
  System.out.println("Value: "+m.group("value"));
}
```

This code will output the following:

```
Next group: ~PHONE_IDX=200
Attribute: IDX
Value: 200
Next group: ~PHONE_DD=100
Attribute: DD
Value: 100
Next group: ~PHONE_KK=50
Attribute: KK
Value: 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard Java library, there is a package `java.util.regex` that may have a viable solution.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("~PHONE_IDX=([0-9]*)", int flags);
Matcher matches = p.matcher(input);
boolean isMatches = m.matches();
```

The parentheses will put the result you're looking for into a group which can be easily accessed without having to substring or iterate over the string again.